# Is it legal and is it appropriate to display religious items in faculty offices in the United States?

Tags: etiquette, united-states, legal-issues, religious-issues

This question is specifically in the context of an American public institution and a generic faculty member, specifically not someone working in religious studies or a similar department. I have noticed over the years that many faculty members have religious items on display in their office or on their office doors, and I was wondering on the one hand whether they are legally allowed, and on the other hand how wise it is to display them while being sensitive to a diverse student population. Here are a few examples from my own experience (all in mathematics).

- Several years ago I had a colleague post the ten commandments outside his office  door.
- I have another colleague who has Bible study books prominently
  displayed on his bookshelf.
- I myself have a poster of the Buddha and a Buddha statue in my
  office, both given to me by a student.
- Somewhat less on topic: a now-retired faculty member used to put ads
  for a Bible study that he held in his home in graduate student mailboxes. (I know many foreign graduate students found this off-putting.)

Comment: Long time ago, the Director of Bands at UNH had a prominently displayed plaque in his office which read "Non Illegitemi Carborundum."   It ain't religious but one wonders if he'd get away with it now.

Comment: I think this question and aesmail's answer are appropriate for most secular nations.

Comment: What if a professor has a Dollar bill on his desk with _IN GOD WE TRUST_ written on it?

Comment: If it was illegal then how could there be professors of religion?????

Comment: @AustinHenley: there are professors of political science, and yet, as I found out below, promoting of political parties is apparently illegal on public university campuses.

Comment: @JimConant I was responding to "Bible study books prominently displayed on his bookshelf" and "Buddha and a Buddha statue in my office." I guess the question boils down to what counts as *promoting*? The fourth bullet point definitely would.

Comment: What's the issue?  The bible is one of the greatest works of literature ever written!  A banner reading "Jesus loves you." on the other hand...

Comment: @AustinHenley: Why does teaching religion imply a need for displayed symbols? [I would personally even go so far to say that to teach religion (never mind which), you do not even have to be religious at all, provided you have an interest in it.]

Comment: @phresnel OP's second bullet point. Someone who studies religion will probably have a lot of material on different religions in his office. So if we allow them to have many books then we have to allow anyone to have at least one book, right?

Comment: @AustinHenley: But there is a big difference between having material for studying, and having material just for display.

Comment: @phresnel Is there? I don't see how anyone could ever prove one or the other. As far as books go and other reading materials, it seems the same to me.

Comment: @AustinHenley: Yes there is, but you are right, none that is provable by objective facts, at least for books. For posters or crucifixes, or even money with religious symbols, simple rules could be established. (Surely, rules could be established for books, too, but then the distinction between religious or not would be arbitrary)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a [document](http://www.calstate.edu/Gc/documents/HolidayReligiousDisplaysThreading1stAmendment.pdf) explaining some of the legal issues involved. Since I have no legal education, I will refrain from commenting too much, it is probably better to consult the document and the references within. With that disclaimer, my understanding is that the main legal tension is between First Amendment rights of the employee and the anti-discrimination clause of the Civil Rights Act, on one hand, and, in the case of a public university, the Establishment Clause on the other. If an unequivocally religious display is placed in a way which may induce others to think that the government (including state government) is endorsing a religion, then the display may be unconstitutional. So, for example, placing the ten commandments in a reception area, like the student accounting office, would likely be a problem. On the other hand, displays *inside* a faculty office are most likely legitimate exercises of free speech. Another consideration is how much disruption the display causes.

To me the ten commandments on the outside of an office door and placing religious ads in mailboxes seem borderline. I have seen posters (for conferences or publications) and comic strip cutouts on office doors, and I always interpreted them as communication from the person who sits in the office, and not university-endorsed communication. So in that sense, I am not sure the endorsement test I mentioned above applies. On the other hand, putting ads in the mail could be reasonably interpreted as something okay-ed by the university, and may be illegal.

One should consult the code of conduct of the institution, which hopefully has more specific guidelines.

Comment: I wonder if historical preservation ever comes into this, because for example the [face of Moses presides over Congress](http://www.aoc.gov/capitol-hill/relief-portrait-plaques-lawgivers/moses).

Comment: I think Nikolov's answer is good. As a broader thought regarding the freedom of personal religious expression in America, I like this saying: > It's freedom *of* religion, not freedom *from* religion.

Comment: @ioSamurai the link you shared suggests that Moses is portrayed as a historical rather than religious figure. If you look at the list of the 23 people with portraits in Congress, it seems clear they were selected as famous lawmakers.

Answer (score 42):

There's a big difference between inconspicuously displaying religiously-themed materials in one's office and effectively proselytizing, as the retired faculty in your example apparently did. The former is I think entirely reasonable, as it's a personal display that does not put any burden on a visitor or guest to the office. Putting religious materials in their inboxes is unwanted, and is inappropriate for a faculty member to do (particularly given the power imbalance involved).

I don't think I've ever received (or heard of) a legal notice that one is *not* allowed to display religious imagery in a personal office. Is it a good idea? Again, I think it's a question of degree. There's nothing wrong with displaying a small cross or Star of David or moon and crescent in one's office. Having a large and ostentatious display, though, would probably put students ill at ease. Similarly, having those materials where you actually meet with students (say, at a conference table in the office) is more "aggressive" than just having it on a bookshelf.

Comment: +1 I agree completely, and maybe I should have left off the last example, since I think we can all more-or-less agree that it is impolite, although I'm still curious about the legal issues. But what about the less extreme examples? Are they less severe breaches of etiquette (or perhaps even against some regulation?), or are they perfectly fine?

Comment: @JimConant On the contrary, they would be considered protected free speech under the First Amendment so long as it's obvious that it's the particular faculty member (or staff member or whatever) and not the University itself doing the promotion. Whether someone may find them off-putting is another matter, but they're certainly not illegal. On the contrary, a policy preventing them would probably be illegal in the case of a public institution.

Comment: @reirab: it's not so clear that this is protected speech. The university owns the offices. I imagine they are legally allowed to control what is posted on the walls, provided it doesn't discriminate against any group. So if all religious items are banned, not just say Christian ones, then that seems like a constitutional policy. Indeed, at my home institution, during a presidential election several years ago, we were instructed that we were not allowed to post political material on our doors or in our offices.

Comment: (We were also instructed that we could only have one political bumper sticker per car parked on university grounds, which seems far less clear legally.)

Comment: It most definitely is not protected speech so long as it's taking place on property owned by your employer.  I know of corporations which have banned all flags in the workplace (basically to avoid near-civil-war conditions).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm not so sure that's correct if it's a public institution. If your employer is a government organization in the US, you do have _some_ free speech rights beyond what you might have working for a private organization, though I'm not sure the exact boundaries or if they have any impact on this situation.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft A public employer is not the same as a private employer. What you say is correct for private employers, but not for public employers.

Comment: @JimConant In the case of the public university, the state actually owns the offices. To quote the document in Sasho's answer, `They [the public employer] may only limit  that right  if  the employee’s speech or display causes a disruption or has the potential to cause disruption, sufficient to outweigh the value of the speech.` Furthermore, as that article also points out, taking any employment action against the faculty or staff member would likely violate Title VII of the Civil Rights Act.

Comment: @reirab: that is quite to the point I agree. So I suppose that when a blanket prohibition on political displays was instituted, the legal rationale was probably that it would cause significant disruption. This also supports aeismail's basic premise that it depends on how aggressive the speech or display is.

Comment: @JimConant Yes. It's also possible, of course, that the political speech rules were simply illegal and went unchallenged. It happens. However, while the first amendment rules should apply equally to the political and religious speech, the Title VII part would not, as far as I know, apply to political speech. I might be wrong on that, but I don't think your political views put you in a protected class with respect to the Civil Rights Act.

Answer (score 4):

At my college we had one faculty who was a very devout christian. The only visible sign was a small bible in the far corner of his obsessively-tidy desk, and topics of religion never came up. Not once. He was also, per christian teachings, rather homophobic. As a significant percentage (like, half) of the students in that program were gay men he rather pointedly never approached the subject.

End result: zero problems. And he got along fine with the 2 gay guys in our section.

Moral: keep your personal beliefs to yourself and everything will be fine.

Comment: It's really questionable to say that Christian "teachings" are themselves homophobic, unless you mean some very specific denomination. And, apriori, I find it unlikely that half of the male student population in *any* school is gay, given less than 10% of American men are gay (and this is a generous estimate afaik).

Comment: @SashoNikolov many christians consider homosexuality to be bad - Leviticus 20:13 is the appropriate reference. And it was an arts program, where you will find a very disproportionate percentage of gay guys, most of whom are Fabulous.

Comment: @SashoNikolov  you've just posted the One True Scotsman fallacy there.

Comment: @SashoNikolov The doctrines of many Churches do (or did) profess that homosexuality is immoral. If I take it from peter's answer that there were only four students in a program, then two being gay is uncommon but by no means hard to believe. IMO, the professor in the answer handled his faith in a professional setting in an exemplary manner.

Comment: Probably it's not a good idea to start dissecting people's faith. This site is really not the place for that type of discussion.

Comment: Part of this is objective. Part of this is subjective. The objective part is fine, the subjective part is not. I'd recommend rewording it to be less pointy.

Comment: Homophobic implies 'fear of', however thinking something is morally wrong doesn't mean you are afraid of it. For example people aren't 'Harpaxophobic' just because they think robbery is immoral.

Comment: Phobias are not specifically fears, but irrational repulsions.

Comment: The relationship between the Old Testament and Christianity has been complicated since at least Paul. Let's not get into theological arguments: I am unqualified for that.

Comment: @ioSamurai: Re: "Homophobic implies 'fear of'": Fortunately, in this modern Internet-connected world, you don't need to make up facts on the spot. You can actually look up words in freely-available online dictionaries, and find out what they really do (and don't) imply.

Comment: @ruakh The suffix -phobia has been re-define in modern times to also mean 'dislike' in certain cases like you say (usually when social/political in nature), but it's still inaccurate as someone can be considered to have immoral behavior regardless of being liked or disliked. It kind of reminds me of [Newspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspeak#Suffixes).

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as many universities are actually private schools, there is no legality behind it unless the university is a publicly funded school. Even in the case of a public institution, it is only illegal if its being taught as dogma. Displaying religious text outside an office is toeing that line.

Over-all, I would refer to your institutions policies on this. On a personal note, what you want to display in your office is fine, just don't get upset when people judge you for it. School is for academia, not religious expression.

Comment: Could you please clean up your prose a bit?  There are a number of grammar problems in this post...

Comment: I'll agree that my English is irregular at best, but it is grammatically correct for non-disciplinary discussion. (I did correct spelling errors, sorry for those.)

Comment: My question is in the context of a public[ly funded] institution.

Comment: As long as there's no proselytizing during class hours, there's nothing directly illegal. However, I do think its generally inappropriate in an academic setting. If enough students/faculty had issue with the display of religious items, a petition could do something about it. For the most part, I find it distasteful, but not inherently wrong.